# FROM_UNIXTIME with YII

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to perform a query in Yii that uses FROM_UNIXTIME. The following code is not working:

```
$model = Banner::model()->findAll(array(
    'condition' => 't.banner_kategori=:parent AND t.status=:status AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(t.publish_date) <= :datetime AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t.unpublish_date) >= :datetime OR t.publish_date = "" AND t.unpublish_date = "" OR FROM_UNIXTIME(t.publish_date) <= :datetime AND t.unpublish_date = "") ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10',
    'params' => array(':parent' => $parent, ':status' => 1, ':datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
));
```

However, when I run this SQL version of the query, I get results as expected:

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(publish_date) AS wew 
FROM banner 
WHERE banner_kategori=1 
AND status=1 AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(publish_date) <= CURDATE() AND FROM_UNIXTIME(unpublish_date) >= CURDATE() OR publish_date = '' AND unpublish_date = '' OR FROM_UNIXTIME(publish_date) <= CURDATE() AND unpublish_date = '') 
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10
```

How can I get the first query to work?

Comment: this is because you mentioned order by and limit in condition, remove `ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10` hope it will work. you can put order and limit in saperate parameter or you can use `CDbCriteria` object

Answer (score 0):

You should use it this way

```
$model = Banner::model()->findAll(array(
    'condition' => 't.banner_kategori=:parent AND t.status=:status AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(t.publish_date) <= :datetime AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t.unpublish_date) >= :datetime OR t.publish_date = "" AND t.unpublish_date = "" OR FROM_UNIXTIME(t.publish_date) <= :datetime AND t.unpublish_date = "")',
    'params' => array(':parent' => $parent, ':status' => 1, ':datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
    'order'=>'created DESC',
    'limit'=>10
```

));